# Is it possible to use asp.net web controls in ashx page?

Tags: asp.net, controls, ashx

Is it possible to use asp:Chart control (or any asp.net web controls) in .ashx page?

Answer (score 1):

No. .ashx is not a page, but a handler. You don't need to put the chart control in a page to work with it. It's still just an object you can instantiate. You can create the chart control in the .ashx code and then save the results of your chart operations to the output of the .ashx.